# The curve function in base R

Tags: r, function, curve

Sorry this might be basic but I am a newbie. I will be making lots of curves so some advice will be useful for me.

I have a function which I want to plot:

```
f <- function(x) sum(4*sin(x*seq(1,21,2))/(pi*seq(1,21,2)))
```

using

```
curve(f, -pi, pi, n=100)
```

Unfortunately ,this does not work for me. Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: Because your function has `sum` in it, it's not vectorized (i.e. `f(1:100)` returns 1 result).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You function isn't vectorized.  At the moment it will only take a single scalar input and output a single return value.  `curve` expects that it should be able to feed in a vector of the x values it wants to plot for and should receive a vector of response values.  The easiest solution is to just use `Vectorize` to automatically convert your function into one that can take vector inputs.

```
f2 <- Vectorize(f)
curve(f2, -pi, pi, n = 100)
```

However, you might just want to write a vectorized version of the function directly.